# discord.py using unix time to send a message every 15 minutes?

Tags: loops, datetime, unix, discord.py

Right now i'm just using datetime and have a loop check every minute if there is a 0, 15, 30, or 45 in the minute place. After a while the bot loses time and sends messages later than the specified time. Is there a way I could make this use unix/fix the desync? or would unix fix the desyncing?

```
import os
import discord
import random
import datetime
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

ecchi = []

time = datetime.datetime.now

class Hentai(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if time().second != 0:
            waittime = 62-time().second
            await asyncio.sleep(waittime)
            if self.time_check.current_loop == 0:
                self.time_check.start()
        else:
            if self.time_check.current_loop == 0:
                self.time_check.start()


# Fetches random image from "hentai" folder:

    for filename in os.listdir('./assets/hentai'):
        path = os.path.join('./assets/hentai', filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            if os.path.getsize(path) > 8000000:
                continue
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            ecchi.append(filename)
        elif filename.endswith('.png'):
            ecchi.append(filename)

    @commands.command(brief = "Automatically sends a random ecchi/hentai image every 15 minutes, or manually send one")
    async def hentai(self, ctx):
        random_image = random.choice(ecchi)
        file = discord.File(f"./assets/hentai/{random_image}")
        await ctx.send(file = file)

# Automatic 15 minute loop

    @tasks.loop(minutes=15)
    async def send_hentai(self):
        channels = (12345678901234567890, 12345678901234567890)
        for channel_id in channels:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            random_image = random.choice(ecchi)
            file = discord.File(f"./assets/hentai/{random_image}")
            await channel.send(file = file)

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1)
    async def time_check(self):
        if time().minute == 0:
            if self.send_hentai.current_loop == 0:
                self.send_hentai.start()
                self.time_check.stop()
        if time().minute == 15:
            if self.send_hentai.current_loop == 0:
                self.send_hentai.start()
                self.time_check.stop()
        if time().minute == 30:
            if self.send_hentai.current_loop == 0:
                self.send_hentai.start()
                self.time_check.stop()
        if time().minute == 45:
            if self.send_hentai.current_loop == 0:
                self.send_hentai.start()
                self.time_check.stop()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Hentai(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import discord
import random
import datetime
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

ecchi = []

def UtcNow():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    return (now - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

class Hentai(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        time = UtcNow()
        if time != 0:
            waittime = 60-time
            await asyncio.sleep(waittime)
            if self.time_check.current_loop == 0:
                self.time_check.start()
        else:
            if self.time_check.current_loop == 0:
                self.time_check.start()


# Fetches random image from "hentai" folder:

    for filename in os.listdir('./assets/hentai'):
        path = os.path.join('./assets/hentai', filename)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            if os.path.getsize(path) > 8000000:
                continue
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            ecchi.append(filename)
        elif filename.endswith('.png'):
            ecchi.append(filename)

    @commands.command(brief = "Automatically sends a random ecchi/hentai image every 15 minutes, or manually send one (Possibly against TOS)")
    async def hentai(self, ctx):
        random_image = random.choice(ecchi)
        file = discord.File(f"./assets/hentai/{random_image}")
        await ctx.send(file = file)

# Automatic 15 minute loop

    currentloop = 0

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5)
    async def time_check(self):
        if self.currentloop > 0:
            self.currentloop -= 1
        time = UtcNow()
        if ((int(time/60)%15) == 0 and self.currentloop == 0):
            self.currentloop = 12
            channels = (751890144977748068, 854619663475277824)
            for channel_id in channels:
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
                random_image = random.choice(ecchi)
                file = discord.File(f"./assets/hentai/{random_image}")
                await channel.send(file = file)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Hentai(bot))
```